# Set react-select options attribute to empty list

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have react-select component and I want it to have empty list inside options.
When I write

```
<Select
options={{ value: '', label: '' }}
/>
```

I get empty select but when I press dropDown Menu I get error

> ScrollManager.tsx:48 Uncaught TypeError: props.options.map is not a
> function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an array of object

```
<Select
  options={[
    { value: '', label: '' }
  ]}
/>
```